# How can I use a specified order of strings to index from a cell array?

Tags: string, matlab, indexing

I am trying to index from a cell aray of a number of potential reference files to use for a comparison. The comparison files have distinct parts of their file names that I'd like to use to specify a single reference file. 
However, I'm only able to return reference files that contain the three distinct parts, in any order. How can I enforce the order?

Example:

The comparison file is:

```
deg_baseFileName = "Test1_female_44k_70dBA_babble7ch_1sp_20k_00dBA_48k"
```

I use strsplit to break the filename into parts:

```
deg_parts = strsplit(deg_baseFileName, "_");
```

The distinguishing parts are:

```
deg_parts(2), deg_parts(4), deg_parts(8)
```

In this case: "female", "70dBA", "00dBA" - in that order.

I use these functions to identify and index with the distinguishing parts:

```
strToFind = {string(deg_parts(2)),string(deg_parts(4)),string(deg_parts(8))}'; % Strings to match
    fun = @(s)~cellfun('isempty',strfind(ref_files,s));
    out = cellfun(fun,strToFind,'UniformOutput',false);
    idx = all(horzcat(out{:}),2);
```

However, the index returns two values from my reference file cell array:
Ref_female_44k_00dBA_babble7ch_1sp_20k_70dBA_48k.wav
Ref_female_44k_70dBA_babble7ch_1sp_20k_00dBA_48k.wav

Both contain the distinguishing parts, but only the second in the correct order.

Is there a way I can enforce the order in my `out` call?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the other parts of the file name always the same, except for the "Test1" vs "Ref" part?

Comment: Yes, the other parts match

Comment: I don't fully understand your workflow for using the distinguishing parts to get reference names. What are the reference names? And could you expand on the issue with both having distinguishing parts but only the second order is correct? That said, you can do fun = @(s)contains(ref_files,s) and probably just loop or even just use idx = contains(ref_files,deg_parts(2)) & contains(ref_files,deg_parts(3)) & contains(ref_files,deg_parts(4)).

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case, where the comparison and reference files only differ in their first part, you can use [`strrep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html):

```
refFile = strrep(deg_baseFileName, 'Test1', 'Ref');
```

If you know what the other parts of the file name will be, and they are the same for all the reference files but differ from the comparison file, you can just use [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to create your file name:

```
refFile = sprintf('Ref_%s_44k_%s_babble7ch_1sp_20k_%s_48k.wav', ...
                  deg_parts(2), deg_parts(4), deg_parts(8));
```

If you don't know or care what the other parts could be, you can generalize the above to create a match expression for use with [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to find the index of reference files with the correct order:

```
expr = sprintf('Ref_%s_[^_]+_%s_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_%s_[^_]+.wav', ...
               deg_parts(2), deg_parts(4), deg_parts(8));
index = ~cellfun('isempty', regexp(ref_files, expr));
```